# move files within a directory to another directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, file-transfer, shutil, delete-directory

I am currently working on a Raspberry Pi that is capturing images 24/7. I am wanting to delete the files in a directory A (where the images are stored) without deleting the directory itself. I know that shutil.rmtree will remove the directory(A) but I have other programs sending files to that directory(A) all the time. So the instant a file is trying to come into a directory A and it does not exist it crashes my Raspberry Pi.

I know that I can move the files within a directory(A) to another directory(B). However using the shutil.copytree or shutilmove only copies the files to my directory B. It does not "cut" the files just copy them.

The only reason I want to do this is because file space is limited and the Raspberry Pi is running 24/7.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at the mv (move) command and the -r (recursive) option. You can type "man mv" at the command line to read the help. We would be better able to help if we new a few additional details like how the files are named? do they have a similar pattern? does it include a date or time stamp? If not can you modify the code to save the files to another directory each hour or day, and then move the entire folder for that day or hour? Also, you can add a check for the directories existence to your code and create it if it does not exist.

Comment: I will look into the MV command. The files that I am wanting to move are jpg images that are being taken at random when the camera is triggered. I am also assigning a random ID to go with the images  . For example XVXI_11242014_08_19_22. Currently the code sends the images every 1 minute from the folder they are saved in on the Rasp PI. I send everything then delete, then recreate.                                                             The key is to try to keep the information moving as close to real time as possible.

Comment: You can do that with a cron job that checks for new files every few minutes.